# Call to a member function tasks() on null のエラーを解決したい

Tags: php, laravel, mariadb

#### エラー内容

以下のエラーが発生しました。

```
Call to a member function tasks() on null
```

#### 状況

index.blade.phpにアクセスしようとしたところ以下のようなエラーが発生しました。
index.blade.phpにアクセスするためにこのエラーを解決し、アクセスできるように実装したいと考えております。

今回のエラーに対して、調べてみて何個か仮説を立てたのですが、原因であろう箇所の対処がわからず解決の糸口が見つけられません。お手数ですが該当箇所に対するアプローチ等のアドバイスをお願いできたらと思い質問致しました。

**実装環境**
Laravel Framework 8.21.0
MariaDB 10.4.17 - mariadb.org binary distribution
Windows 10

#### エラーファイルと該当箇所

**TaskController.php**

```
use App\Models\Task;    //なかったので追加
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateTask;//CreateTaskコントローラをインポート

class TaskController extends Controller
{

    public function index($id)
    {

        //全てのフォルダを取得する
        $folders = Folder::all();

        //選ばれたフォルダを取得する
        $current_folder = Folder::find($id);

        // 選ばれたフォルダに紐づくタスクを取得する
        $tasks = $current_folder->tasks()->get(); // *エラーの該当箇所

    return view('tasks/index',[
        'folders' => $folders,
        'current_folder_id' => $current_folder->id,
        'tasks' => $tasks,
    ]);

}
```

#### 自分の中で立てた仮説と結果

仮説⓵
そもそもtasks関数が存在していない

`php artisan tinker` でデータベースの中身を調べたところ

```
>>>App\Models\Task::find(1)
>>>null
```

しかし

```
>>> App\Models\Task::find(3)
=> App\Models\Task {#4085
     id: 3,
     folder_id: 1,
     title: "サンプルタスク 1",
     due_data: "2021-01-14",
     status: 1,
     created_at: "2021-01-13 17:42:27",
     updated_at: "2021-01-13 17:42:27",
   }
```

モデルファイルも確認でき、task関数がないという線はないと推定。

仮説②
$current_folderの値がNULLである

→var_dumpの結果がNULLならオブジェクトの生成がうまくいっていない
var dump($folders)の時点では値が取得できており
$folders = Folder::all();のコードには恐らくコードに問題はないと推定

しかし `var_dump($current_folder);` してみたところ `$current_folder;` がNULLだった。
`php artisan tinker` では以下の通り値が取得できている。

```
>>> App\Models\Folder::find(1)
=> App\Models\Folder {#4087
     id: 1,
     title: "プライベート",
     created_at: "2021-01-13 17:42:20",
     updated_at: "2021-01-13 17:42:20",
   }
```

**$current_folder = Folder::find($id);**
恐らくこのコードに問題がありそうだが、具体的にどこに問題があるのか分からず...
findメソッドで値が取れないのが疑問点です。

#### 参考ファイル

**Folder.php**

```
<?php
    
    namespace App\Models;
    
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    
    class Folder extends Model
    {
        public function tasks()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Task');
        }
    }
```

**Task.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
// この行を追加
use Carbon\Carbon;

class Task extends Model
{
    const STATUS = [

        1 => [ 'label' => '未着手', 'class' => 'label-danger' ],
        2 => [ 'label' => '着手中', 'class' => 'label-info' ],
        3 => [ 'label' => '完了', 'class' => '' ],
    ];

    public function getStatusLabelAttribute()
    {
        //状態値
        $status = $this->attributes['status'];

        // 定義されていなければ空文字を返す
        if (!isset(self::STATUS[$status])) {
            return '';
        }

        return self::STATUS[$status]['class'];
    }

    public function getFormattedDueDateAttribute()
    {
        return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $this->attributes['due_date'])
            ->format('Y/m/d');
    }
}
```

**web.php**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/
Route::get('/folders/{id}/tasks','TaskController@index')->name('tasks.index');

Route::get('/folders/create', 'FolderController@showCreateForm')->name('folders.create');
Route::post('/folders/create', 'FolderController@create');

Route::get('/folders/{id}?tasks/create','TaskController@showCreateForm')->name('tasks.create');
Route::post('/folders/{id}/tasks/create', 'TaskController@create');
```

[DB内容]
⓵foldersテーブル
[image: foldersテーブル]
[foldersテーブル]

[image: foldersテーブルデータ構造]
[foldersテーブルデータ構造]

⓶tasksテーブル
[image: tasksテーブル]
[tasksテーブル]

[image: tasksテーブルデータ構造]
[tasksテーブルデータ構造]

Comment: 画像は外部サイトではなく、この質問中に直接貼り付けてみてください。

Comment: $idはどんな数値が渡ってきていますか？

Comment: keitaro_so さん　返信ありがとうございます。　var_dump($id)をしたところ{id}がかえってきました。この数値は私の想定していなかった数値だったので原因究明を致します。ありがとうございます

Comment: cubickさん　返信ありがとうございます。　ここでの質問が初めてということもありマナーがしっかりと分かっていませんでした。外部サイトにすることによって、見えにくくしてましたでしょうか？

Comment: 外部サイト云々は[こちら](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)を参考に。「外部のサイトには誰もがアクセスできるわけではありません。また、リンクも時間の経過とともに切れることがあります。」